# Applescript - how do I affect the "main" window of an app if it's not at the front?

Tags: applescript

Logic has a "main window" which is not always technically at the front (there can be smaller floating windows etc). So I cannot do this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Logic Pro"
    get value of UI element [xyz] of the front window
end tell
```

The main window is not consistently named (changes depending on the name of the saved project) so I cannot do this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Logic Pro"
    get value of UI element [xyz] of window "my project"
end tell
```

Is there some way of consistently referring to the "main window"?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways:

1. Check if the window is the main window

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Logic Pro X"
       tell (first window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
           -- do something
       end tell
   end tell
   ```
2. Check if the window is a document window

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Logic Pro X"
       tell (first window whose value of attribute "AXDocument" starts with "file://")
           -- do something
       end tell
   end tell
   ```